# Visual Studio Online Jmeter throws exception: Unable to load or invoke class: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops

I'm trying to run a load test using the Visual Studio Online support for JMeter tests. I'm getting an error below. I tried these 2 settings but with the same results

```
<stringProp name="CookieManager.implementation">org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler</stringProp>

<stringProp name="CookieManager.implementation">org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler</stringProp>
```

based on the advice from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1f5b0fa-bcce-49db-842a-a98757460d0a/jmeter-cookiemanager-unable-to-load-or-invoke-class-hc4cookiehandler?forum=TFService)

> Unable to load or invoke class:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler
>   org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassTools.construct(ClassTools.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.testStarted(CookieManager.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassTools.construct(ClassTools.java:100)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported
>   cookie spec standard  at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy.getCookieSpec(CookiePolicy.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler.(HC3Coo

Comment: are you using JMeter 3.x? I think they dropped support for HC3CookieHandler in latest Jmeter.

Comment: to create the test I used JMeter3 - this uses HC4CookieHandler - but it does not work in vs-team-services. Than I tried  HC3CookieHandler based on this info https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1f5b0fa-bcce-49db-842a-a98757460d0a/jmeter-cookiemanager-unable-to-load-or-invoke-class-hc4cookiehandler?forum=TFService

Comment: You can send the email to vsoloadtest@microsoft.com.

Comment: hmm I think I found my answer it seems vs-team-services only supports  Apache JMeter 2.13 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing

Comment: @Bogdan You can post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer it seems vs-team-services only supports Apache JMeter 2.13