# vsts jmeter loadtest java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops

I'm trying to run a jmeter load test in vsts but keep getting the following error on all URL's.

> Non HTTP response code: java.lang.NullPointerException,Non HTTP
>   response message: null,Thread Group
>   1-1,text,false,None,983,1,1,https://****hidden for
>   security****/,0,ISO-8859-1,1,1,Agent000

It looks like it's doing the request. I think it might be using the Java implementation instead of the defined HttpClient4 implementation. Also I'm a bit concerned about the ISO-8859-1 in the log. Shouldn't this be UTF-8? And if so, how do i force it to be UTF-8.

When I run the jmx-file on my local dev-machine all works just fine. Both in jmeter 2.13 r1665067 and 3.3 r1808647

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looked at the real jmeter.log file in the result zip-file where i was looking in the response csv-file at first. Found some interesting thing in there.

First of all. VSTS load test is currently running version 3.2 as stated in the log file.

> 2017-10-19 13:29:31,805 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 3.2 r1790748

Then i also found the following error in there (and that's been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422476/visual-studio-online-jmeter-throws-exception-unable-to-load-or-invoke-class-or))

> Unable to load or invoke class:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler

Now downloaded the right version of JMeter (as found in the Jmeter.log file, currently 3.2). In my case I then opened and edited the jmx-file and set all implementation settings back to an empty value. Save and upload to vsts load test and all runs just fine.